# Android Google Wallet

Tags: android

Is it possible for an third-party application to use Android services (with appropriate Intent Filter) to listen to transaction made using [Google Wallet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wallet)? Basically can a third-party application sniff what kind of product was bought?

Comment: Given that Google just announced the product a week ago, I doubt there's a full blown API for it yet.

Comment: If google provide this provision that will help the developer to work on NFC related stuffs more closely. It will also encourage the people use the NFC concept.Also google has to release this app in all countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is neither an Android version supporting Google Wallet at the moment neither a Google Wallet app, there is only speculation left at this point of time.